# Display box with plot after hitting actionButton() in modularized shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, module, box, shinyjs

In the modularized shiny app below Im trying to display both the plot and its box when I hit the `actionButton()`. Although it was working for the plot when I tried to do the same logic for the box both are not displayed at all.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
# Some data
data<-structure(list(scientificName = c("Turdus merula Linnaeus, 1758", 
                                        "Passer domesticus (Linnaeus, 1758)", "Cantharellus cinereus (Pers.) Fr.", 
                                        "Flammulina fennae Bas", "Mycena crocata (Schrad.) P.Kumm.", 
                                        "Lepista luscina (Fr.) Singer", "Mycena permixta (Britzelm.) Sacc.", 
                                        "Rhodophyllus byssisedus (Pers.) Quel.", "Rhodophyllus porphyrophaeus (Fr.) J.E.Lange", 
                                        "Panaeolus rickenii Hora"), decimalLatitude = c(52.204429, 51.387818, 
                                                                                        52.176667, 50.066111, 49.179167, 49.419444, 52.3, 52.3, 49.419444, 
                                                                                        49.179167), decimalLongitude = c(21.189275, 19.62673, 19.088056, 
                                                                                                                         19.502778, 22.434722, 20.380556, 20.566667, 20.566667, 20.380556, 
                                                                                                                         22.434722)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 32L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
                                                                                                                                                    41L, 42L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                    ))
data$year<-c(1990,1989,2003,1990,1980,1990,1989,2003,1990,1980)
# Define the side panel UI and server
sideUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    
    uiOutput(ns("ye")),
    uiOutput(ns("scient")),
    actionButton(ns("action"),"Submit")
  )
  
}

sideServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      # define a reactive and return it
      react<-eventReactive(input$action,{
        
        omited <-subset(data, data$scientificName %in% isolate(input$sci)&data$year %in% isolate(input$yea))
      })
      
      output$ye<-renderUI({
        pickerInput(
          inputId = session$ns("yea"),
          label = "Year", 
          choices = sort(unique(data$year),decreasing=F),
          selected = unique(data$year),
          multiple = T
          
        )
      })
      
      output$scient<-renderUI({
        data <-subset(data, data$year %in% input$yea)
        
        pickerInput(
          inputId = session$ns("sci"),
          label = "Scientific name", 
          choices = unique(data$scientificName),
          selected = unique(data$scientificName)[1], 
          
        )
      })
      
      counted<-eventReactive(input$action,{isolate(react()) %>% 
          group_by(year) %>% 
          summarise(count=isolate(n())
          )
        
      })
      return(list(react = react, counted = counted, sci = reactive(input$sci),yea=reactive(input$yea), btn = reactive(input$action)))
    })
}
# In this case this server not needed but using uiOuput/renderUI in real case
# sideServer <- function(id) { moduleServer(id,function(input, output, session) { })}




plotUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    shinyjs::hidden(
      div(
        id = "hiddenbox", 
        
        box(
          title = h3("Incidents Map", style = 'font-size:20px;color:black;
                     font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;'), 
          status = "primary", 
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          collapsible = TRUE,
    plotlyOutput(ns("plot"))
        )))
  )
}

plotServer <- function(id, city, sci,yea,btn) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$plot<-renderPlotly({
        
        fig <- plot_ly(data=city(), x = ~as.factor(year), y = ~count, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers+lines')
        
        fig%>% layout(title = paste("Count of", isolate(sci()),"through the years"),
                      xaxis = list(title = "Years",tickangle=45),
                      yaxis = list (title = "Count"))
      })
      # ----show hiddenbox----
      observeEvent(btn(), {
        shinyjs::show(id = "hiddenbox")
      })
    })
}

# Build ui & server and then run
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(sideUI("side")),
  dashboardBody(useShinyjs(), plotUI("plotPl"))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # use the reactive in another module
  city_input <- sideServer("side")
  plotServer("plotPl", city_input$counted, sci = city_input$sci,yea=city_input$yea,btn = city_input$btn)
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
id = ns("hiddenbox")
```

is the answer